# Query to be fine tuned

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

This being my first question in SO

I am using a query which is ::

```
SELECT   column1, column2, COUNT(*) 
FROM     myTable 
GROUP BY DATE(logged_date) 
HAVING   COUNT(*)>10
```

**Mytable contaings 2 million records, and the column logged_date is of type datetime.**

The above query is takink aroud 15 seconds to execute.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Add an index to `logged_date` if not existing. And examine the `explain select column1...` output

Comment: Add more information to your question. Is logged_date indexed? What is the execution plan? Is there anything you have tried?

Comment: @juergend: Thanks for your response, but the logged_date column is indexed

Comment: Try grouping by logged_date instead of DATE(logged_date). I believe I've read that performing any transformation on a field, no matter how trivial, will prevent the index from working.

Comment: @octern: Yes exactly but the column logged_date has date and time value, but I want to group it by day, Unless I call the DATE function my purpose won't be solved, Any further help would be appreciated

Comment: In that case, try creating a new indexed column, populate it with DATE(logged_date), and then group by that.

Comment: Will indexes really matter if the query has to aggregate the whole table anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome.
It would be best to also provide the table schema. Nevertheless, I will make some guesses:

The logged_date is a TIMESTAMP column or a DATATIME -- is that so? Which is the reason for doing DATE() on that column.

Your best option, if this is a query you wish to optimize, is to add *another* column, which is `logged_date_day` (the first name is already confusing, the second as much :) )

This means supporting both at the same time (but my next guess is that you only `INSERT` it one, not to be update again -- so this is not too much of an effort).

You would then have to index the new column, and do the `GROUP BY` on that column.

PS

Technically speaking, `SELECT column1 FROM some_table GROUP BY another_column` is not a valid query. MySQL allows it when your **sql_mode** does not contain [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by). I recommend that you look into this.

Answer (score 0):

I am also worried about grouping on logged_date but showing column1 and 2, this might not give you the expected results, so better to group on all cols or use a function like max or min around column1 and 2

nevertheless, you might consider something like this :

make sure everything in the group by is keyed togther:

```
alter table myTable add key (logged_date (10), column1,column2);
```

changed query :

```
SELECT   left(logged_date,10) as ldate , column1, column2, COUNT(*) 
FROM     myTable 
GROUP BY ldate,column1,column2 
HAVING   COUNT(*)>10
```

Comment: Adding `column1, column2` to the `GROUP BY` clause may change the output altogether. This should only be done if both are directly dependent upon `ldate`.